# window.history.replaceState() not working as I expect

Tags: javascript, html

is there some way to replace url with JavaScript without reload? For example

```
www.url.com/index.php/presenter/view/../
```

to

```
www.url.com/presenter/view/../
```

?  I've tried it with history.replaceState function but it is only changing the url after `index.php`..

```
function parseUrl(){
    currUrl = window.location.href;
    verify = currUrl.indexOf("index.php");
    if(verify != -1){
        newUrl = currUrl.substring(0,verify-1);
        newUrl += '#'+currUrl.substring(currUrl.indexOf('index.php')+10,currUrl.length);
        if(window.history.replaceState){
            window.history.replaceState(null, this.title, newUrl);
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = newUrl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show your code? As you are only changing the path, this should work. But note that `replaceState` is not for *replacing* the URL but for replacing the current history entry. If you use `pushState`, the user will see new URL, but will still be able to use the back button to return to the previous URL (before you changed it).

Comment: I need have all links ajax driven so I am changing the window.location.hash at standard..But for example RSS links are generated "right" as index.php/... That is wanted behaviour but I need redirect incomig users to the hashed version of url..And I wanted to do it without reload(I only need to have the URL without these superfluous parameters from estetic reasons)
I added the code to my question..

Comment: How does `newUrl` look like after you made all the modifications?

Comment: OH..it is working now..apparently it seems to be:DI really dont know I let my code wait for later and now..Pretty nice..But you may refer to there is bad increment (+10 instead +11)..that was my mistake..So thanks and I will now pray for less IE positive visitors of my site

Answer (score 4):

Try using [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) - perhaps it's cross-browser support for the HTML5 History APIs will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML5 History API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html) can do this, but isn't supported by most browsers (only FF4, and Chrome AFAIK)

GitHub are using it for their [Tree Slider](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slidera).

Comment: It seems he is already using the API but it does not work correctly for him.

Answer (score 0):

1. change the file system location of your application so that it reflects the url you want: www.url.com/presenter/view/
2. use an index.html shell
3. configure your web server to open index.html by default
4. use ajax to grab your data and insert it into your html file.